# Why am I getting this compilation error in my abstract base class?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, abstract-class

I'm trying to extend this plugin for my own use...

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/blob/master/Connectivity/Connectivity/Connectivity.Plugin.Abstractions/BaseConnectivity.cs

But when I copy the code over to Visual Studio, I'm am getting some error.

[image]

Do I need to import some special framework in order to use the '=>' operator and 'Invoke' Method? This is an abstract base class. I am using VS2013

Comment: Are you using VS2015?

Comment: No this is VS2013. Is that what the issue is?

Comment: The problem is you're trying to use C#6 syntax in VS2013.

Comment: ?. is a feature from C# 6, available in Visual Studio 2015 only. Read about that here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm new to C# coming from Java.

Comment: @cFrozenDeath also trying to use an expression body off a method (`=>`) is C#6

Answer (score 14, accepted):

?. is a feature from C# 6, and as well as the => operator (when used for expression-bodied members), is available in Visual Studio 2015 only.

Read about them here [null-conditional operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) and here [=> operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311046.aspx)

C# < 6 syntax:

```
protected virtual void OnConnectivityChanged(ConnectivityChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ConnectivityChanged != null)
        ConnectivityChanged.Invoke(this, e);
}
```

Comment: add something to mention the `=>` for a method body and I'll upvote.

Comment: You should also address Jonesopolis' comment

Comment: also, I don't mean to just nitpick, but it's not that the `=>` operator itself that's new to C# 6.0, only it's use for expression-bodied members. You should probably clarify that as you're re-working your answer, especially since your link goes to the `lambda` page instead of the new feature.

Answer (score 4):

`?.` is `Null-conditional operators` in C#6. You is using C#6?
[C#6 featured](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6)

Replace this code to

```
if(ConnectivityChanged != null) 
{ 
    ConnectivityChanged.Invoke(this, e); 
}
```

This is equivalent to the our code `ConnectivityChanged?.Invoke(this, e);`

Answer (score 2):

This should do it.

```
protected virtual void OnConnectivityChanged(ConnectivityChangedEventArg e)
{
   if(ConnectivityChanged != null)
   {
       ConnectivityChanged.Invoke(this,e);
   }
}
```