# How to translate ReceiveReady method in NetMQ from C# to F#

Tags: c#, f#, c#-to-f#, netmq

I'm working with a library that does not have F# documentation, only C#. Having no familiarity with C# I'm having a bit of trouble. Reading through the [documentation](http://netmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/poller/) for NetMQ, there is one line that I'm having trouble translating:

For context, here is the full example:

```
using (var rep1 = new ResponseSocket("@tcp://*:5001"))
using (var rep2 = new ResponseSocket("@tcp://*:5002"))
using (var poller = new NetMQPoller { rep1, rep2 })
{
    rep1.ReceiveReady += (s, a) =>    // ??????
    {
        string msg = a.Socket.ReceiveString();
        a.Socket.Send("Response");
    };
    rep2.ReceiveReady += (s, a) =>    // ??????
    {
        string msg = a.Socket.ReceiveString();
        a.Socket.Send("Response");
    };

    poller.Run();
}
```

Specifically, I don't know what `rep1.ReceiveReady += (s, a) =>` means in the context of C# as well as how to translate it to F#. Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Please see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34161972/3932049 for information on the => operator

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto : This has nothing to do with expression-bodied members though, this is just a lambda...

Comment: I'm the author of NetMQ,  happy that you are using NetMQ and found an answer. You can contribute to the project with adding F# docs or some example.

Comment: Its a great library. Actually in some cases the NetMQ docs provide a better explanation of some concepts than the Zguide. I very well might contribute some F# examples in the future. Thanks for the great work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rep.ReceiveReady += (s, a) => { /*...*/ };` is subscribing to the `ReceiveReady` event with a lambda function. Here is a direct F# translation:

```ml
use rep1 = new ResponseSocket("@tcp://*:5001")
use rep2 = new ResponseSocket("@tcp://*:5002")

use poller = new NetMQPoller()
poller.Add rep1
poller.Add rep2

rep1.ReceiveReady.Add (fun a -> let msg = a.Socket.ReceiveString ()
                                a.Socket.Send "Response")
rep2.ReceiveReady.Add (fun a -> let msg = a.Socket.ReceiveString ()
                                a.Socket.Send "Response")

poller.Run ()
```

Further reading on event handling in F# can be found in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/members/events). Note, however, that F# can also treat events as observables, which is likely to be considered more idiomatic.