# C# set and get shortcut properties

Tags: c#, properties, get, set

I'm watching an instructional video on C# and they showed a shortcut (type "prop", tab twice)  it generates this

```
public int Height { get; set; }
```

So then he went on a shortcut about using => instead of this.  It tried to combine the two but got an error in Length:

```
    class Box
{
    private int length;
    private int height;
    private int width;
    private int volume;

    public Box(int length, int height, int width)
    {
        this.length = length;
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
    }


    public int Length { get => length; set => length = value; } // <-error
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Volume { get { return Height * Width * Length; } set { volume = value; } }

    public void DisplayInfo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Length is {0} and height is {1} and width is {2} so the volume is {3}", length, height, width, volume = length * height * width);
    }

}
```

Volume works fine, but I was interested in seeing if I can shorten the code like I'm trying to do with Length.

1. What am I doing wrong, can it be done that way? 2. Is there a shorter was to set properties (am I on the right track)

Comment: Seems to be working for me: https://tio.run/##fZJNT8MwDIbPy68wO3VV962dChyAw5CGhITEDohDtoUuUpZMSboxVf3txU3TtWyISD3Udl4/fuO16a@VZkWRGi4TeDsZy3YxWQtqDLxqlWi6g4x0jKWWr@Gg@AZeKJeBsRovfHwC1YnpYcmD@oYVfncg2RHwL5jMovEogumsFxPMDBZMJnaLBZNRTEin86ikUYINlppbtuCSBd05E0JFsFRabG4gG@XdCJqrqNPJSU48HvYgGQE8e80P1DLg0oJwpfFVfMt4srXX8SPf/FV@UCLdMeR0iXQlcPpyqKZF1JKNGqmeu1FxlcduuRmIevQ23TlbaWC2zXjOOlVMtkDRgjZX2dubm0HCUOm@bgSm/YsqBypSFkMOwyHc9pnWSl9KzSscJ@UEsPyyZumg/i15dw56ogw0s6mWtXjoFUIPXhIZV1cZ3ybNfw3rVvCJm72gp2f5pYJLw/9YK28ON@VKAZUb77SLjKtIZXMZmCCKQu9ZzVIGp@Uq1g9fP7q7EzXI3uWwlg/9SpxfLS@KHw

Comment: You don't need a private `length` field in your current example, just like `height` and `width`, you can remove the private fields and just use auto-properties with `PropertyName { get; set; }`

Comment: You also probably shouldn't have a `set` for `Volume`, since it's a calculated field. If someone changed `Volume`, how would you adjust the other size properties?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting this compilation error in my abstract base class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34161885/why-am-i-getting-this-compilation-error-in-my-abstract-base-class)

Comment: for `Volume`, you might just mean `public int Volume => Height * Width * Length;`

Comment: @RufusL , I get that.  And he did say those fields were no longer necessary, I am interested in the methodology.

Comment: @MarcGravell thanks, that actually works a lot better.

Comment: @TheLyrist the error box states (field) int Box.length Only assignment, call, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement EDIT: I was using C#6.  need to upgrade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `=>` [expression-bodied member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members) syntax as a shortcut for read-only properties in C# 6.0 (you can't use them with a `set`) and in C# 7.0 they were expanded to include `set` accessors as you have in your code (which require backing fields, also as you have).

Most likely you're on C#6 so you're getting an error on the `set` syntax.

You asked how to shorten your code, and since you don't have a need for a private backing member (you aren't modifying the value in the `set` or `get` accessors), it would be shortest to get rid of them and just use [auto-implemented properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties) for the ones that the user can set. Then you can use `=>` for the `Volume` property, since it should be read-only (because it's a calculated field):

I believe this is the shortest code for the class you've described:

```
class Box
{
    public int Length { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Volume => Height * Width * Length;

    public Box(int length, int height, int width)
    {
        Length = length;
        Height = height;
        Width = width;
    }

    public void DisplayInfo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Length = {0}, Height = {1}, Width = {2}, Volume = {3}", 
            Length, Height, Width, Volume);
    }

}
```

Comment: Neat, this makes the code much simpler.  thanks.  EDIT:  Another user did mention I was using the older version, which was the reason why I got the initial error.  But he was downvoted and deleted his answer.